# How to submit a form only if a date input is not Sunday?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

The following HTML markup is a form for inserting dates.

If the day is Sunday, the user shouldn't be able to submit the form, otherwise the form should be submitted normally.

But, I haven't mentioned the form action and method.

How can I do this with JavaScript?

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Departing</td>
                    <td>Returning</td>
                </tr>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="date" name="departing" required>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="date" name="returning" id="rtndate" required>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Cheack Availability">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can do this with javascript. Have a look at this link http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp. Give it a try. if you're still stuck leave a comment

Comment: @Pindo please don't link to w3schools resources, they tend to be outdated and sometimes they are just plain wrong. Instead please link to actual w3c specification documents or a more reputable resource like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

Comment: @Pindo–please don't reference [*w3schools*](http://www.w3fools.com/), use ECMA-262, W3C or MDN as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. here's a more reliable link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

Comment: Not all browsers support input type date, those users will get a plain text input. You should provide a hint for the format, e.g. *d/m/y* or similar. Then you should provide a listener on say the blur or change events that reads the input value, parses the string to a Date, then checks if the day is 0 (i.e. Sunday) and gives the user an error message. Also validate on submit and prevent submission if the date doesn't suit.

Comment: I've edited your question to clarify and simplify for those answering and for future viewers, if I have deviated from the intent of your question please let me know. However I still don't understand what you want by saying 'But, I haven't mentioned the form action and method.' maybe you could clarify what your intention is there.

Comment: @-RobG yep,Firefox & IE doesn't support input type date.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `getDay()` from input value here is an simple example

**Updated** now working with major browsers

```js
function whatsTheDay() {
var inDat = document.getElementById('dateInput').value;
var inDate = new Date(inDat)
    if(inDate.getDay() == 0){ // 0 = sunday , 1 = monday ..etc
//alert('sunday');
// do any thing
document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('submit').value = 'disabled';
document.getElementById('err').innerHTML ='sunday not allowed'
}else{
//alert('not sunday');
document.getElementById('submit').value = 'submit';
document.getElementById('err').innerHTML = 'this day is allowed';
document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
}
}

 function sumitable(){
var inDate = document.getElementById('dateInput').valueAsDate;
if(inDate.getDay() != 0){
document.forms["myform"].submit();
}
}
```

```css
input{
display:block;
margin:10px;
width:200px;
border-radius:15px 0 15px 0;
border:none;
padding:5px;
border:solid 2px green;
font-size:18px;
color:green;
}
input#submit{
background:gold;
}
```

```html
<form id="myform">
<input type="text" placeholder="user data"/>
<input id="dateInput" type="date" onchange="whatsTheDay()"/>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" onclick="sumitable"/>
</form>
<p id="err"></p>
```

Comment: Doesn't work at all in IE 11 (or any other version).

Comment: Great, except that `new Date(inDat)` might return any of a number of values, one of which *might* be a suitable Date object, but most of which won't, depending on the browsers. That's why it should never recommended to  use the Date constructor to parse strings, they should be manually parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the idea is:

1. Fetch the data from the fields
2. Transmit fetched data to the backend service

You can make it simply with jQuery and PHP:
(to use this code, you have to integrate the jQuery script to your site's code: 
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js 
)

submit.js (Jquery):

/* FETCH DATA FROM THE FIELDS AND SEND THEM THROUGH AN AJAX POST */

//ON CLICK TO BUTTON WITH ID = "button_submit" DO THE FOLLOWING

```
$(document).on('click', '#button_submit', function () {

    //GET DEPARTING FIELD'S VALUE
    var departing = $("[name='departing']").val();

    //GET RETURNING FIELD'S VALUE
    var returning = $("[name='returning']").val();

    //FOR DEBUG CASES YOU CAN PRINT THE VALUES FOR THE CONSOLE (REMOVE OR COMMENT IT WHEN YOU DONE DEVELOPMENT)
    console.log('Departing date: ' + departing);
    console.log('Returning date: ' + returning);

    //OPTIONAL VALIDATION SCRIPT HERE

    //SEND THE DATA TO THE BACKEND SERVICE WITH AN AJAX POST
    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/your_form_processor.php', //URL OF THE BACKEND SERVICE (use PHP here)
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            departing: departing,
            returning: returning
        } //FIRST TAG: Data name, SECOND TAG: Value
    })
        .done(function () {
        //YOU CAN PROVIDE FEEDBACK HERE ON A SUCCESSFUL POST
        console.log("success");            
    })
        .fail(function () {
        //OR YOU CAN PROVIDE FEEDBACK HERE ON A FAILED POST
        console.log("error");            
    });
});
```

On the server side, you can grab data with the

$variable_name=$_POST["dataName"];

method.

your_form_processor.php (PHP):

```
<?php
echo 'Departing date: ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["departing"]) . '!';
echo '<br>'
echo 'Returning date: ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["returning"]) . '!';
?>
```

You can check the script in action on JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dizajner/gLt3e7bw/1/

Happy Coding!

Comment: The OP asked for a javascript solution, no library tagged or mentioned. Query + php is unlikely to be what is wanted.

Comment: It is possible, that the OP doesn't know yet the fact that one can use libraries for javascript. As far as i know, basically jQuery is javaScript. I can't see the native tag anywhere, so my suggestion is let the OP decide what he/she find useful.

Comment: The point is that in order to implement your answer, the OP must learn at least 3 technologies that weren't asked for and aren't necessary to solve the problem. Yes, jQuery is javascript but it introduces an entirely different API.